# android google analytics integration

Tags: android, xml, google-analytics

In my project I have google play services dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

I'd like to add google analytics to my project
When I follow according to spec and add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
```

Gradle says there is conflict between google play services versions
If I change `play-services-analytics` version to `10.0.1` it runs ok, but now I can't compile due to google's utility class `AnalyticsApplication` needs xml resource called global_tracker:

```
mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
```

In the doc its said I have to download google-services.json configuration file.I already have this file.Also there is no reference where should I get this xml.Somewhere on SO there is mention gradle should generate this resource.I  have searched through the project folder - there is no such file.The question is where do I get this xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new folder under the `res/` directory and call it `xml`. Then create a new  `XML resource file` called `global_tracker.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

<!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

Comment: Thanks.Its sad official documentation skips this moment.BTW:I have already linked my google analytics account to my firebase app, so I suppose there should be auto-generated tracking id.Where can I find it?

Comment: You should be able to find your Tracking ID in your Google Analytics account. Check [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032385?hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tracking id for firebase-linked app

Comment: Did you [connect your Firebase app to Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en)?

Comment: Are you trying to setup [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) or [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none). In your picture, the app at the top (is this the app you're working on?) was implemented using [Firebase Analytics](http://imgur.com/a/vrvss). If you implement it this way, you will not get a tracking id, and don't need to implement Google Analytics with the above library. You just need to connect your Firebase app to Google Analytics. If you want GA, you will need to select Google Analytics Services SDK in the previous picture.

Comment: I'd like to send my events to GA so I need some kind of tracking id to send it with the library above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136638/discussion-between-drew-and-undefined).